# Eclipse forgets about added libraries

Tags: android, eclipse

Out of the blue, Eclipse gives me a terrible headache I dont how how to fix. All worked fine, and then this (cf. image)
I can still see the google_play_services in the libs folder, but I cant find a way to tell Eclipse it should use it again

[image]

remove and add doesnt work:
[image]

Comment: Just remove it and then add it.

Comment: try to add both library and project in same drive.

Comment: You should import the google-play-services_lib as a new project and then mark it as library , and you will see it in the second picture you post.

Comment: Import required libraries in your workspace first then try to add it in your project, if it still forgets,Clean all the projects , restart eclipse and all done

Comment: ok, did a new import. Next problem: Android Dependencies have a little red cross next to google_play_service_lib.jar

Answer (score 0):

All libraries and your project should be kept in same folder. than again import all(including your project). Also check for Appcompat version.